# Can add effects to the text in JTextArea, like alpha, shadow by using graphics2d or grahics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, jtextarea

i have a JTextArea with text inside it. I was wondering if i can add effects to the text in the JTextArea itself like alpha or shadow by using the Graphics2D.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be no people here! This is not a nuclear weapon guys.. in the internet each one benefit from the others, some problems you cannot find and you should solve it yourself. as i did here ! I solved my own problem perfectly,

```
Graphics g = textArea.getGraphics();
int x = image.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(string) - 4;
    int y = fm.getHeight();
g.drawString(textArea.getText(), x, y);
 float alpha = 1.0f;
    int alpha2 = slider1.getValue();
    alpha = (float) alpha2 / 100;
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
```

Thats it ! with a little things that i will not add them here to avoid give the benefit for someone that dose not deserve it..

Answer (score 0):

If you use a JTextPane instead, you can use a StyledDocument, or even simpler, HTML. One can separately set styles, or inline them. Maybe not the pletora of effects of doing it oneself with Graphics(2D), but easy.